# how to load xml file into big query

Tags: xml, python-2.7, google-bigquery

Im trying to load xml file into the google bigquery ,can any one please help me how to solve this . I know we can load JSON ,CSV and AVRO files into big query . I need suggestion/help, Is the any way can i load xml file into bigquery

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is probably to convert your XML file either to CSV or to JSON and then load it. Without knowing the size and shape of your data it's hard to make a recommendation, but you can find a variety of converters if you search online for them.